# Coloring every other row run into an issue when macro run twice

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that shades every other row. When I run the sub twice though It shades every row. The new code I tried continued to take shade away from column "B" and then shade every row for the rest of columns.

```
Sub ShadeEveryOtherRow()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Wa As Worksheet
Dim a As Integer

Set Wa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")
With Wa
    For a = 2 To 15
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow Step 2
            .Cells(i, a).Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(221, 221, 221)
        Next i
    Next a

End With

End Sub
```

Tried adding this above the i = statement:

```
If i = 3 Or 5 Or 7 Or 9 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: I can't replicate that. There must be something you're not telling us.

Comment: Therein lies the issue probably. You can do this with conditional formatting anyway. Your second snippet needs to be `If i = 3 Or i=5 'etc ` but is redundant in any case.

Comment: SJR it is ran from a button that uses a call feature for multiple macros. Maybe that is why?

Comment: Are you adding any rows at any point?  That would cause (the following) odd and even rows to be changed.

Comment: So, as the macro can be called multiple times, perhaps the first thing to do is to remove all shading and then shade every other row from a fresh start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 - VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShadeEveryOtherRow()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim Wa As Worksheet

    Set Wa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")

    With Wa

        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow Step 2
            .Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 15)).Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(221, 221, 221)
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Method 2 - Convert the range to table

1. Select the whole range - Home Tab - Styles section - Format as table - select one style

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional formatting to do this instead of a macro.

Add a conditional format of `=AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0, COUNTA($A:$A)>=ROW())` and Format the cells so that they are filled with your `RGB` values.

[image]
[image]

Then apply this to your range `$B:$O`

[image]

Giving you the results of
[image]

This would auto-update if rows are added/removed and you wouldn't have to run it manually each time. This will work if there aren't any blank cells mixed in your column A otherwise you will have to change the formula to find the last row in the column

If you want to use the macro way I'd modify your code to set both even and odd rows using something like the following

```
Sub ShadeEveryOtherRow()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Wa As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set Wa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")
    With Wa
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            With .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 15))
                If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    .Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(221, 221, 221)
                Else
                    .Interior.Color = xlNone
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

This will ensure all odd rows have their fill removed. However, personally I prefer the conditional formatting route.